# How to configure `Ctrl + L` shortcut in IDEA IDE's emulated Git Bash to behave the same as `clear`?

Tags: git-bash, jetbrains-ide, goland

Using JetBrain's GoLand IDE with the emulated terminal GitBash for Windows 10.

Let's say I've done a bunch of `cd` command to find myself in `c:\Users\USERPROFILE\go`.

Using `clear` command neatly clears the terminal windows leaving only the following:

```
~/go
$
```

But using keystrokes `Ctrl + L` leaves me with just:

```
$
```

Using either command in (non-emulated) GitBash results the same as the first case, which is preferred.

How to set GoLand configuration to behave the same as external terminal?

Comment: No way to behave the same ATM, feel free to fill out a new ticket on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA